# Best way for retrieving single record results in LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

If I query a table with a condition on the key field as in:

```
        var user = from u in dc.Users
                   where u.UserName == usn
                   select u;
```

I know that I will either get zero results or one result. Should I still go ahead and retrieve the results using a for-each or is there another preferred way to handle this kind of situation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault. There's a lot to LINQ that I haven't used much of yet, and I can tell that there's a lot more out there.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var user = (from u in dc.Users
                   where u.UserName == usn
                   select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

The [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549141.aspx) method returns the first element of a sequence that satisfies a specified condition or a default value if no such element is found.

Comment: Might be worth nothing that "System.Linq" is required for the extension methods.

Answer (score 19):

Why not something like

```
var user = dc.Users.SingleOrDefault(u=> u.UserName==usn);
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault will do a TOP 1 operation for efficiency. Unfortunately SingleOrDefault does not do a TOP 2 and selects the entire set.

Comment: Not sure if that is always entirely true, perhaps depending on version or the exact syntax. I tend to see sql statements like these when i use SingleOrDefault: "SELECT TOP (2) col1, col2 FROM (SELECT col1, col2) AS Extent1 WHERE..." So it's kinda both top 2 and not. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Also it should be noted that First/FirstOrDefault/Single/SingleOrDefault are the point of execution for a LINQ to Sql command. Since the LINQ statement has not been executed before that, it is able to affect the SQL generated (e.g., It can add a TOP 1 to the sql command)

Answer (score 4):

I would use First() or FirstOrDefault().

The difference: on First() there will be an exception thrown if no row can be found.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the SingleOrDefault method.

```
var user = (from u in dc.Users
                   where u.UserName == usn
                   select u).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Contains(username) as opposed to "=="

```
var user = (from u in dc.UserInfo 
                      where u.Users.Contains(username) 
                      select u).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Summarized from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/first-firstordefault-single-singleordefault-in-c-sharp):

1. `First()`
   It returns the first element of a sequence.
   It throws an error when there is no element in the result, or source is null.
   We should use it if more than one element is expected and you want only the first
   element.
2. `FirstOrDefault()`
   It returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no element is
   found.
   It throws an error only if the source is null.
   We should use it if more than one element is expected and you want only the first
   element. It's also good if the result is empty.
3. `Single()`
   It returns the only item of a sequence.
   This will throw an exception if the result contains 0 or more than 1 elements.
   We should use it, when we know that exactly one element is expected but neither 0
   nor 2 or more.
4. `SingleOrDefault()`
   It returns single specific element, and if the element is not found, it returns
   the default value of it.
   This will throw an exception if the result contains 2 or more elements.
   We should use it when we know that 0 or 1 element is expected as result.

Comment: Please always mention the source of information when copying content in order to prevent plagiarism claims.