# How does EF implement SingleOrDefault

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I read that [LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204678/794234) does not efficiently implement SingleOrDefault (look at Damien's comment).  Is that also true for LINQ to EF?

I would want something that only selects a maximum of two records (since two already breaks the Single rule), along the lines of:

```
Function SingleOrDefault(source As IQueryable(Of T)) As T
    Dim candidates = source.Take(2).ToList()

    If candidates.Count = 2 Then
       Throw
    ElseIf candidates.Count = 1 Then
       Return candidates(0)
    Else
       Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Which question are you asking?

Comment: That is how Singleordefault is implemented in EF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL that is generated by EF for singleordefault is:

```
 SELECT TOP 2 ....
```

If 2 records come back it throws an exception. There is only one trip to the database.

You can check it by running the SQL profiler.